# What's the alternative for SystemProperties class methods and it's usages in java or kotlin?

Tags: java, android, android-11, android-developer-api

I want to save the system settings for example if the user enabled glove mode or not. Currently, I am using SystemProperties.java class's set and get methods. But in android 11 I can't use these methods because the class itself is marked hidden and methods so by @hide. So I am looking for a similar kind of solution in java/ kotlin. For eg.

```
SystemProperties.set(SYSTEM_PROPERTY_GLOVE_MODE, Integer.toString(newState));
int sysprop_status = SystemProperties.getInt(SYSTEM_PROPERTY_GLOVE_MODE, -1);
```

When I was looking for the solution I found few useful links but those are not enough - [Google ticket](https://groups.google.com/g/android-platform/c/XHITx5elJwM?pli=1), from android developer [Implementing System Properties as APIs](https://source.android.com/devices/architecture/sysprops-apis). I am not sure method from System class like [setProperty()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and [getProperty()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System#getProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) can be useful.

**Note. Using reflection won't work anymore in android 11.**

Comment: Why not just use `SharedPreferences` or a simple file?

Comment: @CommonsWare seems a good suggestion, I was wondering, why other developers used that SystemProperties.java? Will we lose its content if we do a factory reset? Because I have a system app where I am saving some settings related system-wide.

Comment: "why other developers used that SystemProperties.java?" -- app developers generally do not use this. What you describe as "Google ticket" is a 3-year-old post from the `android-platform` Google Group, and the "Implementing..." that you link to is from the AOSP. `SystemProperties.java` is for use by the platform, for people creating custom Android builds and system apps, not for ordinary developers creating ordinary apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thanks for explaining to me this. So SharedPreferences will work here? or We have System.get/setProperty() method also.

Comment: "So SharedPreferences will work here?" -- I cannot answer that, as I do not know why you chose `SystemProperties` in the first place. You went waaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaay out of your way to use it, going against the vast majority of what has been written about Android app development. That is why I phrased my initial comment as a question.

Comment: As I said, I need to use it for one of my system app, and yes I'm creating custom android build.

Comment: OK, but if this is only needed for one system app... why would it need to be a device-wide property? If you are expecting that other apps would need this, then perhaps a device-wide property makes sense. Even then I would consider other approaches (e.g., a custom system service, because it feels like "glove mode" is something that changes on the fly, so apps might need to react to changes).

Comment: Hello again @CommonsWare, why a system service? Because I just want to save a key value only somewhere that it can be shared between multiple apps. One APP can set it using set(key, value) and others can get it by using get(key) method. For eg., if I want to disable the device charging by setting some key -value(that I am currently using SystemProperties.set()).